Is there a danger when using Bleach toilet cleaner tablets and flushable cat litter?
I know cat pee contains ammonia. I have been using a slow release toilet cleaning tablet that contains bleach. I'm also using flushable corn-based kitty litter.
I know in general you aren't supposed to mix Chlorine and Ammonia - Is there a risk if I continue to do this? Obviously I'm not sticking my head in the toilet but should I be worried about the gas sticking around?

There's ammonia in human effluvia too. If the tablet is safe for humans, I don't think cat waste will be a problem.
